# Deserialization using RestAssured but without following jsonpath

Tags: java, json, deserialization, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have the following response body from a server:

```
{
  level1: {
    main1.abc: "A string",
    main1.def: "Another text",
    main2.abc: "Something else"
  }
}
```

and I'm using restAssured to process the response. I would like to get it as map with key representing the full string and their related values.

I've done it before however here the dot notation is automatically processed as jsonpath, so it gets deserialized as well, resulting in the following linked hash map:

```
level1 (key) > main1 (key) > abc (key) > "A string" (value)
             > main1 (key) > def (key) > "Another text" (value)
             > main2 (key) > abc (key) > "Something else" (value)
```

by calling

`then().extract().body().jsonpath().getMap("");`

I'm not able to find any specific settings in jsonPathConfig to control this.
Am I looking at the wrong place?

thx!

Comment: Which RA version do you use? I've tested with version 4.4.0, it works fine.

Comment: Where does the backend service lays? How is it serializing the response for your HTTP calls? Note that the input is invalid JSON and you should be fixing your backend serialization (if you are the owner) instead of fiddling with RestAssured configuration (which should be working fine for a doted JSON key if the latter is well formatted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Rest-Assured version 4.4.0, it works fine for you json.

```
@Test
void SO_69573815() {
    String text = "{\n" +
            "  \"level1\": {\n" +
            "    \"main1.abc\": \"A string\",\n" +
            "    \"main1.def\": \"Another text\",\n" +
            "    \"main2.abc\": \"Something else\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = JsonPath.from(text).getMap("");
    System.out.println(map.get("level1").get("main1.abc"));
    //A string
}
```

Comment: Does you `text` variable value looks like the main OP data?

Comment: thanks @lucasnguyen17 ... your answer triggered me to check if I indeed receive the mentioned json.. It turns out I can control the flat reply with a queryParam from the server which I didn't pass it properly in the GET .. so it wasn't restAssured but the actual response. thanks again